# Double Click inside brackets

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to enable a setting in VS Code that allows for selecting everything inside brackets by double-clicking inside the opening bracket?

For example: if I double-click the cursor inside the opening bracket, everything within the brackets is selected instead of the just the first word.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two options.  First, there is a command:

```
editor.action.selectToBracket
```

which does not have a default keybinding.  Here is an example keybinding.

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+alt+\\",
  "command": "editor.action.selectToBracket"
}
```

It works nicely within an html tag (as in actually inside the tag like within the class attrtibute) , for instance.  Try it and see if you like it.

IMO, working much better is the extension [expand region](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=letrieu.expand-region).  It increases, or decreases, the selected scope from wherever you start.  It is applicable to more situations than the command above.

Comment: OK, thank you, however I was hoping to get something akin to Eclipse behaviour, where if you double click inside a bracket or quotes it selects everything until the next bracket and or quote...
The Expand Region plug-in only supports a few languages at the moment it looks like and I am using C++.

Comment: A key binding is not a solution to wanting to use the mouse to select between brackets. Double clicking a bracket was one of the first things I tried to do in VS Code, and I was disappointed that it didn't work.